# Is there any way I can use the downloaded pre-trained models for TIMM?

Tags: pytorch, computer-vision, huggingface

For some reason, I have to use TIMM package offline. But I found that if I use ***create_model()***, for example:

```
self.img_encoder = timm.create_model("swin_base_patch4_window7_224", pretrained=True)
```

I would get

```
http.client.RemoteDisconnected: Remote end closed connection without response
```

I found the function wanted to fetch the pre-trained model by the URL below, but it failed.
https://github.com/SwinTransformer/storage/releases/download/v1.0.0/swin_base_patch4_window7_224_22kto1k.pth

Can I just download the pre-trained model and load it in my code like in Huggingface? (I have checked the timmdocs but found nothing mentioning this.)

Comment: check the *source* of your library. it'll download the data and **cache** it somewhere. put your data there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can download all models somewhere local. ( all models can be found in the [project's release section](https://github.com/rwightman/pytorch-image-models/releases)).

The on your offline system. put them under:

```
~/.cache/torch/hub/checkpoints
```

to be more clear this is the `ls` return for the mentioned folder on my computer:

```
tf_efficientdet_d7x-f390b87c.pth
tf_efficientnet_b0_aa-827b6e33.pth
tf_efficientnet_b7_ra-6c08e654.pth
```